# Wildcard character in field delimiter - reading .csv file

Tags: sql, csv

A .csv file gets dumped nightly onto my FTP server by an external company. (Thus I have no control over its format, nor will they change it as it's used by several other companies.)

My mission is to create a job that runs to extract the info from the file (and then delete it) and insert the extracted data into a SQL table.

This is the format of the info contained within the .csv file:

```
[Message]Message 1 contains, a comma,[Cell]27747642512,[Time]3:06:10 PM,[Ref]144721721
[Message]Message 2 contains,, 2 commas,[Cell]27747642572,[Time]3:06:10 PM,[Ref]144721722
[Message],[Cell]27747642572,[Time]3:06:10 PM,[Ref]144721723
```

I have a SQL Server 2012 table with the following columns:

```
Message varchar(800)
Cell varchar(15)
Time varchar(10)
Ref varchar(50)
```

I would like to use something like the SQL bulk insert (see below) to read from the .csv file and insert into the SQL table above.

```
BULK INSERT sms_reply
    FROM 'C:\feedback.csv'
    WITH
    (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    TABLOCK
    )
```

The delimiter in the .csv file is not common. I was wondering if there was a way for me to use a wildcard character when specifying the delimiter. e.g. '[%]'?

This would then ignore whatever was between the square brackets and extract the info in between.

I cannot simply use the commas to delimit the fields as there could be commas in the fields themselves as illustrated in the .csv example above.

Or if anyone has any other suggestions, I'd really appreciate it.

TIA.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "not common". Is the delimiter always `%` ? Or it may change ? Or ?

Comment: By "not common", I mean that it's not always a specific character like ",". Check out the .csv file at the top and you'll notice that the fields I need are actually delimited by [Message], [Cell], [Time], and [Ref]. I.e. a word inside square brackets is the delimiter.

Comment: I still see commas separating each field.  In fact, if they were not there, it wouldn't be a .csv file.

Comment: Yes Dan, there are. However, there may be comma's in the actual field as well. These are SMS replies from users, thus they could use commas in the messages they send us. This is why I cannot rely on the commas alone to delimit the fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to overcome this by using a handy function I found [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/code/WorkingWithFiles/uftReadFileAsTable.txt)
which comes from an article located [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/).

This function returns each line in the .csv file and then I use string manipulation to extract the fields between the "[variable_name]" delimiters and insert directly into my SQL table.

Clean, simple and quick.

NOTE: You have to enable OLE Automation on your SQL server:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be:

1. Bulk load the csv file into a staging table.  All columns accepting data would be varchar.
2. Do an sql update to get rid of the brackets and their contents.
3. Do whatever other processing is required.
4. Insert data from your staging table to your prodution table.